# Swift : Array Tuple is getting empty in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, viewdidload

I'm getting json data in `setLabel` function. I'm adding the datas into array tuple in here. I need the call `getData` and I'm calling properly. I see the datas in `setLabel`, but when I try in `viewDidLoad`, tuple is getting empty. It should be full, because I'm calling `getData`. I don't get the issue.

By the way I'm using football-data.org api.

Code :

```
var groupA:[(rank: Int, name: String, playedGames: Int , points: Int)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        getData("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/424/leagueTable")

        for (ranks, names, plays, point) in groupA{
            print(ranks, names, plays, point)
        }
}

func getData(urlString: String){
    let url = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    url.addValue("//my token is here", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    url.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(url) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.setLabels(data!)
        })

    }

    task.resume()
}

func setLabels(MatchData: NSData){
    do{
        if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(MatchData, options: []),
        dict = json as? [String:AnyObject],
        standings = dict["standings"] as? [String:AnyObject],
        a = standings["A"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{


            for i in 0..<a.count{
                groupA.append((rank: a[i]["rank"] as! Int, name: a[i]["team"] as! String, playedGames: a[i]["playedGames"] as! Int,  points: a[i]["points"] as! Int))
            }
            groupA.sortInPlace{ $0.3 != $1.3 ? $0.3 > $1.3 : $0.0 < $1.0 }

            print(groupA) 
        }
    }
    catch{
        //error


    }
}
```

Comment: You are fetching data asynchronously. Your data has not yet returned when your for loop executes. So `setLabels` has not been called and your array is still empty.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. But how can I call it? I'm thinking this now. Any idea?

Comment: You could move your for loop to after `print(groupA)`. That is when you know your array has been populated.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked. I want to use data in `tableView` and the loop doesn't work. Same problem in here. So how can I solve this?

Comment: Typically when you are finished parsing fetched data you call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you so much :)

Comment: For further queries you should post new question